# How do you load credentials in a Ruby controller without storing them in the file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, rubygems, sinatra

I am working on a Twilio application using Sinatra. Since I dont have too much experience with Ruby (but am excitedly learning), I am having a problem with separating the credentials from my file. I would like to upload the files to a repository, but I want to keep the sensitive credentials in a separate file that would be imported.

The file is currently composed of:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twilio-ruby'

account_sid = "xxxxxx"
auth_token = "xxxxx"
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

from = "+12341231234"

friends = {
  "+1231231234" => "Lenny"
}
friends.each do |key, value|
  client.account.sms.messages.create(
    :from => from,
    :to => key,
    :body => "Hey #{value}, Monkey party at 6PM. Bring Bananas!"
  )
  puts "Sent message to.#{value}"
end
```

How would I properly load the `account_sid` and `auth_token` lines to a separate file? What is the best practice for storing credentials like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two common practices for this are:

1) Store the variables as environment variables on your system and access them with `ENV`

```
account_sid = ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]
auth_token = ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
```

2) The other is to store them in a YAML file on your server and then when you deploy your application, symlink this file to where it should be in your repository.  This file should be in your `.gitgnore`

```
#config.yml

twilio:
  account_sid: "xxxxx"
  auth_token: "xxxxx"
```

Then in your application

```
require 'yaml'
config = YAML.load_file("config.yml")
account_sid = config[:twilio][:account_sid]
auth_token = config[:twilio][:auth_token]
```

There are also [several gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Configuration_Management) for configuration management, the only one I have used personally is [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) but it is rails specific.

Comment: For the third code block, did you mean config.yml and also account_token instead of account_sid twice?